# MySQL bug in the DELETE clause

Tags: mysql

Has anyone experienced a situation like this?

I accidentally typed the DELETE command in the wrong syntax (MySQL version 8.0.22). The command should never have worked, but it not only worked, it also deleted all data from the table:

***Syntax: DELETE FROM test WHERE 123456;***

Note that neither the column name nor the conditional operator was specified, but even so the command was executed without errors and deleted all data from the table.

The code 123456 is an example but can be any code.

Test it on any version of MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `cod` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod`),
  KEY `ix_tmp_autoinc` (`cod`)
);

INSERT INTO `test`
(`name`)
VALUES
('MySQL bug');

INSERT INTO `test`
(`name`)
VALUES
('MySQL bug 2');

DELETE FROM test WHERE 123456;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test;
```

Comment: There is no bug here. The clause `WHERE 123456` is (i) legal and (ii) always true, so every row was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid statement, absolutely in accordance with the syntax for the DELETE command described at [DELETE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html). On the `DELETE` statement page it says that `WHERE` must be followed by a `where_condition`, which is described on the [SELECT statement page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). There we find that a `where_condition` can be either a `Function and Operator`, or it can be an [Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html). Looking at the Expression page we find the following hierarchy:

```
expr
 |
 boolean_primary
   |
   predicate
     |
     bit_expr
       |
       simple_expr
         |
         literal
```

So a `where_condition` can be a literal, which is exactly what you gave it. It may not have been what you meant, and it may not have done what you intended, but from the standpoint of MySQL syntax it's perfectly legal.

Comment: And `0` and `NULL` are treated as `false`.  Other values are treated as `true`.

Answer (score 2):

What is playing out here are MySQL complex casting rules.  When you ran the following query:

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE 123456;
```

MySQL expected a boolean expression following `WHERE`.  It didn't find that, but it did instead find an integer literal.  It turns out that MySQL will treat an integer literal as being "truthy," and so it will evaluate to true.